# Want to Display time to the main view of a game?

Tags: android, graphics, view, textview

I am currently developing a simple game for Android where the main action occurs on my class GameView, which is simply an extension of View.

I want to add some text showing the time in the top left corner of my GameView, and would like to know the best way of implementing this?

I used foolowing code to display

public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
        {
            TIME=(int) (millisUntilFinished/1000);

```
        timeCanvas.drawText("time= "+TIME, 30, 30, timePaint);

            invalidate();

    }
```

But it cannot display properly. Its override every count increment.
Is there any other method to display time?

Also i used text view. but couldnt set TIME as text in this customized viewGive solution or any sample code to display....

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html) article help you

```
private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
public void run() {
   final long start = mStartTime;
   long millis = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
   int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);
   int minutes = seconds / 60;
   seconds     = seconds % 60;

   if (seconds < 10) {
       mTimeLabel.setText("" + minutes + ":0" + seconds);
   } else {
       mTimeLabel.setText("" + minutes + ":" + seconds);            
   }

   mHandler.postAtTime(this,
           start + (((minutes * 60) + seconds + 1) * 1000));
```

}
};

to start

```
mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
```

to stop

```
mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
```